# Android Activity Task in foreground

Tags: android, android-activity, launch, activity-stack

I have 3 activity tasks A-B-C

```
<activity android:name=".LoginActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:noHistory="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity android:name=".DashboardActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name" >
</activity>
<activity android:name=".CreateNewPolygonActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:launchMode="singleTask"
              android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
              android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden">
</activity>
<service android:name=".services.RecordCircuitService"
             android:enabled="true" >
</service>
```

And I have a `Service` with GPS using `LocationManager`.

My application has this logic:

1. On launcher icon clicked - > start login activity
2. After login - > login activity is finish(); and start dashboardActivity
3. In the dashboard I start `CreateNewPolygonActivity` and start the `Service` with GPS
4. Press HOME (this is reorganize `RecordActivity` to  foreground)

after I have some mistakes work

1. open `CreateNewPolygonActivity` with `onCreate`
2. open `DashboardActivity`

I think I have a problem with my task organization.

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 0):

You won't achieve the desired result by setting `launchMode="singleTask"` for your activity. Android won't create a separate task for this because you've not set the `taskAffinity`. In any case, you don't want to do this by using `launchMode="singleTask"` because this causes more problems than it solves. This launch mode is intended for HOME-screen replacements only!

Remove ``` launchMode="singleTask"`` from ```CreateNewPolygonActivity`

Also, you should remove `android:noHistory="true"` from your login activity. This isn't necessary either. Since you've already finished the login activity when the user starts the DashboardActivity, when he presses the BACK button, it won't return to the login activity (which I assume is what you wanted).

Once you've done these things, please tell us what is still broken.

Comment: Goes on to describe the situation
1) When I press the HOME button and not connected to other applications intrnet then the activity returns to normal
2) If the application uses the activity is recreated

Perhaps it is a time of loss network (mcc mnc flags) and when the new network is reconnection?

Comment: Sorry, I'm having a lot of trouble understanding. Have you looked in the logcat to see if there are any errors?